# Book application calling function

Tags: javascript, arrays, class

I have this book donation system it has the following classes (Book , Donor)
I've created the objects directly

*These are some of the objects that I've created them.*

**App**

```
    let Book1 = {

        bookId : 112233,
        title : "HarryPotter",
        author: "J. K. Rowling",
        imageUrl :"image",
        donor : "Daniel Radcliffe",
        status : "Available",
    }
let Book2 = {

    bookId : 112233,
    title : "Jane Eyre",
    author: "Charlotte Brontë",
    imageUrl :"image",
    donor : "Mia Wasikowska ",
    status : "Pending ",



}

    let Donor1 = {
        donorId : 2244,
        firstname : "Daniel",
        lastname : "Radcliffe",
        phoneNumber : 99088988,
        street : "Platform 9¾",
        city : "London",
        email : "R@hotmail.com",
        password : "123",
    }
    book.addBook(Book1);
    book.updateBook()
    book.getDonorBooks(2244)
```

**BookCatalog**

```
class BookCatalog  {

    constructor(){

        this.books = [];
  }


    addBook(book) {
        this.books.push(book)

    }

    updateBook(){


       return this.books.reduce(pre , curr) =>{

            if(pre.bookId == curr.bookId )

                curr.bookId = 1111

        }


}



    getDonorBooks(doonrId){


    }


}

module.exports = BookCatalog ;
```

**updateBook() should do take book as an input and Updates the book that having matching bookId.**

**getDonorBooks() should do take donorId  and Returns all the books donated by a particular donor.**

***I don't know how to do these two methods.***

Comment: "updateBook() should do take book as an input" : well it doesn't. Look into [`functions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions) if that part's unclear, for a start. Also "update the book" doesn't mean much unless other data is passed to the function (such as an object that holds what should be updated).

Comment: your code have a  common mistakes in your code like book object has name which can be duplicate It should contain id of donor .

Comment: @Jeto can you show me in code how to make the update

Comment: @Noor Stack Overflow isn't here to do the work for you, at least if you didn't give a proper try yourself. You seem to be missing some basics. Take a look at that link above and edit your post with your attempts then we will help.